# How can I use useMemo React Hook in this example

Tags: react-native

What am I doing wrong here? I want to utilise useMemo so that my RenderItems component doesn't keep flickering when the state (`Data2`) changes. The `Data2` array is in place of an item in my apps state. In practice, `Data2` is data fetched from an api, and thus is subject to change and update.

I'm not looking for an alternative in this case, I'd just like to know how to use useMemo in this example - thanks!

```
import React, { useMemo } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text
} from 'react-native';

const CoursesWidget = (props) => {

  const Data2 = [{ id: '11' }, { id: '22' }, { id: '33' }];

  const coursesArray = Data2;

  const RenderItems = useMemo(() => {
    return (
      coursesArray
        .map((course) => {
          return (
            <View key={course.id}>
              <Text>{course.id}</Text>
            </View>
          );
        }),
      [coursesArray]
    );
  });

  //const Finito = useMemo(() => RenderItems(), [])

  return (
    <View>
      <RenderItems />
    </View>
  );
};

export default CoursesWidget;
```

Snack: https://snack.expo.dev/rr8toaABT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that needs to be changed is moving the dependency array that you pass to useMemo to be the last parameter, and instead of calling it in the return like a jsx component, you put the value in brackets since it's not really a function anymore:

```
import React, { useMemo } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text
} from 'react-native';

const CoursesWidget = (props) => {

  const Data2 = [{ id: '11' }, { id: '22' }, { id: '33' }];

  const coursesArray = Data2;

  const RenderItems = useMemo(() => {
    return (
      coursesArray
        .map((course) => {
          return (
            <View key={course.id}>
              <Text>{course.id}</Text>
            </View>
          );
        })
    );
  }, [coursesArray]);

  //const Finito = useMemo(() => RenderItems(), [])

  return (
    <View>
      { RenderItems }
    </View>
  );
};

export default CoursesWidget;
```

Here's the snack: https://snack.expo.dev/5GbI-k8Pb

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use a `state` and a `FlatList` instead of creating the `elements` using `map`. There is no need to use `useMemo` at all in this scenario and it will not fix your issue.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  FlatList,
  SafeAreaView
} from 'react-native';

const CoursesWidget = (props) => {

  const [data, setData] = useState([{ id: '11' }, { id: '22' }, { id: '33' }])

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{margin: 20}}>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
           return <View>
              <Text>{item.id}</Text>
            </View>
        }}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default CoursesWidget;
```

Here is an updated version of your [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@pgrepds/widget-carousel-state).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and helpful response! However, I'm sure that I will need to utilise useMemo due to the nature in which my redux state handles the data. I've modified my question slightly to make it clearer perhaps?

Comment: I don't think that you need it. If your state changes, react on it using a `useEffect` and update your `data` state. This will rerender the `Flatlist` with no flickering.